# Android Attributing the ID for Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

i can simply set item into Spinner from database, now i want to get id's text into spinner,but i can do it and i can not find id's name selected by user. for example in HTML i can set simple set id to `<select>` like with Spinner:

```
 <select>
  <option value="1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="2">Saab</option>
  <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

now how to do this action for adnroid Spinner?

```
    Cursor c = G.db.getAllMoshtarian();
    if (c != null && c.getCount () != 0) {
        do {
            String name_moshtari1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
            list_name_moshtarian.add(name_moshtari1);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();

    list_name = (String[]) list_name_moshtarian.toArray(new String[list_name_moshtarian.size()]);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list_name_moshtarian);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    name_moshtarian.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. You need to call `setOnItemSelectedListener()` and provide a Listener which will be called back when the user selects an item. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: @David Wasser Hi David, in html we can assign id for values. i want to get value's id after choose item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set an `OnItemSelectedListener` on your `Spinner`. When the user selects an item, `onItemSelected()` will be called with the position in the array. You can use the position as an index into your `String` array, or your can use the position as an "ID" (this will be an array index, from 0 to the number of items - 1), or you can store the ID in a parallel array, or a hashmap or whatever.

```
name_moshtarian.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // The user selected item "position"
        String name = list_name_moshtarian.get(position); // Get the name
    }
});
```